# "little" vs. "a little"

Tags: grammar, adjectives, exam-questions

> Her mother has _____ chance of recovery:
>   a. little
>   b. a little
>   c. the little
>   d. none?

I need an exact answer, I am unable to understand the usage of *little* and *a little* as explained on this and all other websites. This sentence could be both positive and negative in my opinion, but it appeared in an exam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) is the most correct English phrasing, probably. This would mean that the mother is very unlikely to recover, which most people would view as a negative outcome.
(b) is a /possible/ answer, but would be more commonly phrased as "a small chance of recovering". This is again a negative outcome, but in context may be slightly more positive, as in "Her mother is very hurt, but has a small chance of recovering." It is quite strange that "a little" would very rarely used in this case by a native English speaker, but, on the face of it, means exactly the same as "a small". 
(c) definitely is not standard English.

Answer (score 1):

**Little as an adjective** is the same meaning as when you use the verb have in the negative + much.

- Her mother ***doesn't have [or hasn't got] much chance*** of recovery.

  Little, therefore, works like ***the negative of the verb have + much*** before an uncountable use** of the word chance. The difference is that it is used in a declarative sentence rather a negative one. Chance can be used as a countable or uncountable noun.

So, it is grammatical to say: not have much chance of a recovery, have no chance of recovery.

[references to come, for now, I am my own reference].

Comment: You need to say why (b) is wrong if you're going to answer. // In 'He has a small chance of recovering', I'd not class the usage of 'chance' as count. It's more of a fixed idiom; 'He has two / seventeen / several ... small chances of recovering' are not available.

Comment: It has to be explained comparatively with the negative  have + much. However, it also works your way: He has a chance of winning/He has three chances of winning/countable versus. And: he has little chance of winning V. He does not have much chance of winning=uncountable. But I see no reason to explain every incorrect option.

Comment: 'He has three/several chances to win the lottery' obviously shows a count usage. 'He has little chance of recovering', where nobody would say 'he has several chances of recovering', doesn't.

Comment: You realize you are making my point right? I said that little chance here  is uncountable, and that little is another form of the negative of have + much. Of course, "he has several chances of recovering" is what no one would say in lieu of it. I agree completely.

Comment: Yes, but you don't explain why this usage has to be considered non-count. In fact, you've still not added any supporting references (though I'm unsure about requirements here on ELL). And you don't explain why 'a little' is incorrect here (after all, 'a small' works). [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/little_1) correctly labels this usage of 'little' determiner rather than adjective.